# how to create new td's from user input dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a data table from user input. i found out this solution that i am making objects from user input and pushing them to an array. after that, I am doing a for loop to make td. but somehow those datas are re writing in the same raw. and previous raw datas are getiing replaced by new input datas.what I am doing wrong here and every time I am refreshing the page the array is getting empty how to prevent this help me out tnx.

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const tdbody = document.getElementById("data");
const carDatas = [];
let count = 0;

class Car {
  constructor(plate, carMaker, carModel, carOwner, carPrice, carColor) {
    (this.plate = plate),
      (this.carMaker = carMaker),
      (this.carModel = carModel),
      (this.carOwner = carOwner),
      (this.carPrice = carPrice),
      (this.carColor = carColor);
  }
}

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  const plate = document.getElementById("plate").value;
  const carMaker = document.getElementById("carMaker").value;
  const carModel = document.getElementById("carModel").value;
  const carOwner = document.getElementById("carOwner").value;
  const carPrice = document.getElementById("carPrice").value;
  const carColor = document.getElementById("carColor").value;

  const carDetails = new Car(
    plate,
    carMaker,
    carModel,
    carOwner,
    carPrice,
    carColor
  );
  carDatas.push(carDetails);

  for (let i = 0; i < carDatas.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = document.createElement(
      "tr"
    ).innerHTML = `<td>${carDatas[i].plate}  </td>
    <td>${carDatas[i].carMaker}  </td>
    <td>${carDatas[i].carModel}  </td>
    <td>${carDatas[i].carOwner}  </td>
    <td>${carDatas[i].carPrice}  </td>
    <td>${carDatas[i].carColor}  </td> `;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

here is my html for table

```
<div class="database">
    <h1>Cars Database</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>LICENCE</th>
          <th>MAKER</th>
          <th>MODEL</th>
          <th>OWNER</th>
          <th>PRICE</th>
          <th>COLOR</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="data"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have tried `+=` for setting `innerHTML`

Comment: use the insertadjacentHTML function instead of setting innerHTML since innerHTML is rewriting everything inside the object everytime you set it.

Comment: thnx, it worked but the table is getting empty if I refreshed the page. how to keep the changes in the table'?

Comment: you need to store it in localstorage and on refresh read the storage. if entry exists, prefill the table

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is bad!

I don't know if this part of your code is working, but if you have an array of objects you should see a function for arrays that is called map

```
   arr.map((object) => {
   return <td>{object.plate}</td>
})
```

this function is example, try to look for documentation